# How to create full horizontal row with Split.js?

Tags: javascript, split.js

I want to use [Split.js](http://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/) for creating my specific layout like

[image: full horizontal row]

```
<div id="a" class="split split-horizontal">
</div>
<div id="b" class="split split-horizontal">
    <div id="d" class="split content"></div>
    <div id="e" class="split content"></div>
    <div id="f" class="split content"></div>
</div>
<div id="c" class="split split-horizontal">
</div>

<script>
    Split(['#a', '#b', '#c'], {
        gutterSize: 20,
        cursor: 'pointer'
    });
    Split(['#d', '#e', '#f'], {
        direction: 'vertical',
        sizes: [15, 70, 15],
        gutterSize: 20,
        cursor: 'row-resize'
    });
</script>
```

but above code does not work.

Can anyone help me? 
How can I create the layout with `Split.js` because does not exist any sample like that in their site?

[Classic sample in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ouzzzxb/)

[My Sample in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qmbywr1/)

Comment: Define `does not work`. And create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @giorgio, I updated my post

Comment: Just a question - why do you need to use a js plugin to achieve that layout - very simple to do in html / css - especially with flex in use.

Comment: @gavgrif, I want to be collapsible and resizable Do you have a better option?

Comment: @user7489391 - I just posted a quick and dirty layout that replicates yours - you don't need an external js thing to do this - its straight HTML / CSS and can bopne in a flash (and responsive) using bootstrap or flex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You where pretty close. First of all you didn't add `content` class to the left/right pain, so they didn't show. Then you mixed up the horizontal split. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8qmbywr1/1/)'s a working fiddle.

```
<div id="a" class="split content"></div>
<div id="b" class="split">
    <div id="d" class="split content split-horizontal"></div>
    <div id="e" class="split content split-horizontal"></div>
    <div id="f" class="split content split-horizontal"></div>
</div>
<div id="c" class="split content"></div>

Split(['#a', '#b', '#c'], {
    gutterSize: 20,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    direction: 'vertical',
});
Split(['#d', '#e', '#f'], {
    sizes: [15, 70, 15],
    gutterSize: 20,
    cursor: 'row-resize',
});
```

Comment: You are rock! :)

Comment: Can each column width be initially set using a fixed flex-basis and controlled via CSS.? For example flex: 1 1 300px;?